# Shifting Complex Baseband Signal with Pilot Tone

Tags: communication

I am trying to shift a complex baseband signal. To do that, I am multiplying by \$e^{(j \times 2 \times \pi \times f_c \times t)}\$, where \$f_c\$ represents the shift amount. The baseband signal has a pilot tone component at DC (0 frequency), and I expected the pilot tone component to be shifted along with the rest of the signal. The pilot tone is prominent, and its power is higher than the average power of the rest of the signal. When I observe the PSD of the unshifted complex signal, I can see the pilot tone at DC.

However, the actual shifted result shows the pilot tone has disappeared. If I shift using \$cos(2 \times \pi \times f_c \times t)\$, I also get a missing pilot tone in the shifted signal.

Has anyone experienced this before? How do I fix this? I have attached a scan of some diagrams of what I am trying to accomplish and what is actually happening.

Thank you in advance.
[image: Shifting Complex Signal with Pilot Tone]

Comment: Try testing your implementation, expectations, and instrumentation by putting in just a DC input, and then a single sinusoid at various non-zero frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out there was an issue with the FFT calculation. The solution was to calculate it from scratch (no pre-built functions), and take the magnitude of the resulting FFT and shifting the spectra as needed.